# Kubernetes DSE Cassandra CommitLogReplayer$CommitLogReplayException

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, kubernetes-pod

I have installed Cassandra on Kubernetes (9 pods) All the pods are up and running except
for one pod, which shows the below error.

```
org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer$CommitLogReplayException: Encountered bad header at position 47137 of commit log /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-600-1630582314923.log, with bad position but valid CRC
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.shouldSkipSegmentOnError(CommitLogReplayer.java:438)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.handleUnrecoverableError(CommitLogReplayer.java:452)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegmentReader$SegmentIterator.computeNext(CommitLogSegmentReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegmentReader$SegmentIterator.computeNext(CommitLogSegmentReader.java:84)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReader.readCommitLogSegment(CommitLogReader.java:236)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReader.readAllFiles(CommitLogReader.java:134)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.replayFiles(CommitLogReplayer.java:154)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recoverFiles(CommitLog.java:213)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recoverSegmentsOnDisk(CommitLog.java:194)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:338)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:527)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:702)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:96)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReadHandler$CommitLogReadException: Encountered bad header at position 47137 of commit log /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-600-1630582314923.log, with bad position but valid CRC
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegmentReader$SegmentIterator.computeNext(CommitLogSegmentReader.java:111)
    ... 12 more
ERROR [main] 2021-09-06 06:19:08,990  JVMStabilityInspector.java:251 - JVM state determined to be unstable.  Exiting forcefully due to:
org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer$CommitLogReplayException: Encountered bad header at position 47137 of commit log /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-600-1630582314923.log, with bad position but valid CRC
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.shouldSkipSegmentOnError(CommitLogReplayer.java:438)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.handleUnrecoverableError(CommitLogReplayer.java:452)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegmentReader$SegmentIterator.computeNext(CommitLogSegmentReader.java:109)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogSegmentReader$SegmentIterator.computeNext(CommitLogSegmentReader.java:84)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:143)
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:138)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReader.readCommitLogSegment(CommitLogReader.java:236)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReader.readAllFiles(CommitLogReader.java:134)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.replayFiles(CommitLogReplayer.java:154)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recoverFiles(CommitLog.java:213)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recoverSegmentsOnDisk(CommitLog.java:194)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:338)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:527)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:702)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:96)
```

Can someone help me out please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, one of the commit log segments got corrupted on the node.

You can workaround the issue by manually deleting this file on the pod:

```
/var/lib/cassandra/commitlog/CommitLog-600-1630582314923.log
```

Interestingly, that commit log segment was created on September 2 (`1630582314923`) but the log entry you posted was from September 6. This indicates something happened to the pod which resulted in the corrupted file.

You'll need to review the Cassandra logs on the pod (not the pod logs itself) to determine the root cause and address it. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to hear that. Cheers!